# Standalone rails Application per model/service.

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, soa

I just read this article trending right now on HackerNews

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3199907

I have been thinking about this for a while after understanding activeResource in rails.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics

I really like the idea of splitting your application into totally separate applications that only communicate through restful API. Including the client.

Can someone explain how this might be a really good or bad idea?

Rails 3.1 has support now for engines (rails app in your rails app) but that just doesn't feel right to me (db migration issues are a pain) - I like the idea of a separate application that communicates over restful http api.

I dont understand everything about SOA or whatever it is called - but just want to get the pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently found myself pondering similar questions, how best to modularise a large application. As a relative Ruby newcomer (< a year), I dabbled with writing Rails APIs, and consuming them with ActiveResource. It didn't feel quite right to me, Rails felt too bloated for the APIs and ActiveResource felt too generic and incomplete for the client.

Then, I read [Service Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails - Paul Dix](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Service-Oriented-Design-Rails-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321659368/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1320525014&sr=8-1), and it was like an epiphany! It covers your specific question of pros, cons & the theory very early on (chapter 1 I think), and does it very well.